# Tkinter: What is faster: Deleting and drawing a new one or Itemconfig?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

On a Tkinter Canvas, what is faster on updating a piece of text, `canvas.itemconfig(text, text='new text')` or deleting the text and writing new text to the screen.

Deleting the text and adding new text:

```
text = canvas.create_text(200, 200, text='old text')
canvas.delete(text)
text = canvas.create_text(200, 200, text='old text')
```

Using `itemconfig`

```
text = canvas.create_text(200, 200, text='old text')
canvas.itemconfig(text, text='new text')
```

Comment: "faster" is a pretty easy thing to measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faster for one item is irrelevant. The canvas has performance problems<sup>1</sup> when it has to manage large numbers of object ids, even if they are the ids of deleted items. Each time you delete and create the text, you are adding another id. If you delete and recreate a text item over and over, eventually you will cause performance problems.

The best solution is to configure the text of an existing item.

<sup>1</sup> I can't cite a reference for this. I've looked around and can't find a definitive write-up, but I've seen this problem first-hand in the past.

Answer (score 0):

As for which is faster, well it really wont make much of a difference, since after all we're talking about fractions of seconds. You could say though that `canvas.itemconfig` is only one line of code, while deleting then re - adding text is 2 lines and 2 commands, so `canvas.itemconfig` might either make it faster or make your code more efficient. So... unless you're facing problems with canvas.itemconfig, I would stick to it for the time being.