# Unable fetch text variable data in class in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to fetch the data from text variable and image in a function name `loopCap` and display it in `__init__` function where I have created a canvas but due to mentioned below error I am not able to move further

**For text Error:**

```
   *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-textvariable"
```

**For Image Error:**

```
self.put_photo = canvas.create_image(70, 250, image=self.photo, anchor='nw')
AttributeError: 'StartPage' object has no attribute 'photo'
```

**Actual Code Sample:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

im = "BG.jpg"
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.ard_stat = read_json(JSON_PATH)
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def loopCap(self):
        with open(JSON_PATH) as json_file1:
            self.data = json.load(json_file1)
            print(self.data)
        if self.data['status'] == 'ACTIVE':  # and (self.data['RH_img']!= 'null' or self.data['LH_img']!= 'null')
            a = self.text.set(self.data['status'])
         if self.data['RH_img'] == 'NA':
         self.img = Image.open(Press)
         self.img.load()
       self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
       self.label['image'] = self.photo
       self.master.after(500, self.loopCap)

 def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.config(bg='black')
        Frame2 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        Frame2.pack(fill='both',expand = True)
        self.photo_back = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        lab_1 = tk.Label(Frame2, image=self.photo_back)
        lab_1.image = self.photo_back
        lab_1.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        canvas = Canvas(Frame2, width=1000, height=700)
        canvas.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo_back, anchor='nw')
        self.text = tk.StringVar()
        canvas.create_text(230, 170, fill="white", font="Times 20 bold", 
        textvariable=self.text, anchor="w")
        self.label = tk.Label(canvas)
        self.put_photo = canvas.create_image(70, 250, image=self.photo, anchor='nw')
        canvas.itemconfig(self.put_photo, image=self.photo)
        self.master.after(500, self.loopCap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions will be a great help.

Comment: [Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method) does not have `textvariable=`. You have to use [Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method)

Comment: hi, can you please share me some example or how should I update it  in code, as I am new to this

Comment: ***"some example"***: Read the given links and [itemconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352958/tkinter-what-is-faster-deleting-and-drawing-a-new-one-or-itemconfig)

Comment: Thanks, It works fine with Text but the same thing when I am trying for image update then I am facing the error ```self.put_photo = canvas.create_image(70, 250, image=self.photo, anchor='nw')
AttributeError: 'StartPage' object has no attribute 'photo'``` can I update image with this ?

Comment: ***"can I update image with this ?"***: Yes, your statement is ok, but you have `photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)`. Should read `self.photo = ImageTk....`

Comment: I am trying to call self.photo from ```loopCap``` function self.photo_back is already displaying the in image in ```__init__``` function. Basically there is 1 static image named ```self.photo_back``` and two different images displaying on the static image (named ```self.photo``` and ```self.photo1```) which are updating through the JSON file (where Image path has been given) after giving certain output, also it keeps on reading the data and image from ```loopCap``` function. main scenario is this and I am able to display the images as background but the other two images are the issues here.

Comment: **1.** Make `canvas = ...` a class member: `self.canvas = ...`. **2.** Do `.create_image(70, 250, image=None`. **3.** Move `self.canvas.itemconfig(...` into `def loopCap`

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing "textvariable=" with "text="

```
canvas.create_text(230, 170, fill="white", font="Times 20 bold", text=self.text, anchor="w")
```